# Distance between origin and a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this problem:
What is the distance between origin and the line $$f(x,y,z) = (-1+t,2,2+2t)\;?$$

How do I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried doing a web search for "The distance between a point and a line"?

Comment: It seems to be you mean "origen" ...

Answer (score 5):

If you can use differential calculus it is a piece of cake. Denote by $\;d\;$ the wanted distance, then:

$$f(t):=d^2=(-1+t)^2+2^2+(2+2t)^2=5t^2+6t+9$$

Differentiate now and equate to zero:

$$f'(t)=10t+6=0\iff t=-\frac35$$

Checking the second derivative or otherwise is easy to prove the above value of $\;t\;$ gives us a minimum, which is

$$f\left(-\frac35\right)=5\cdot\frac9{25}+6\cdot\left(-\frac35\right)+9=\frac95-\frac{18}5+9=\frac{36}5$$

and thus the distance is

$$d=\sqrt{f(x)}=\frac6{\sqrt5}=\frac{6\sqrt5}5$$

You have to prove/answer two things: (1) why the general setup works, and (2) why can we take the square of the distance and *not* merely the distance. Of course, the last one makes things simpler since one has not to mess with the square root that appears in distance...and the question is why?

**Only with analytic Geometry:** The line is

$$l_1:\;\;(-1,2,2)+t(1,0,2)$$

Thus, we look for the line $\;l_2\;$ through the origen and perpendicular to $\;l_1\;$:

$$l_2:\;(0,0,0)+r(a,b,c)\;\;,\;\;\text{and it must be that}\;\;(a,b,c)(1,0,2)=a+2c=0\;\text{(why?)}$$

So let us choose the director vector $\;(a,b,c)=(2,2,-1)\;$ , and then

$$l_2 :\;r(2,2,-1)=(2r,2,-r)$$

Check where $\;l_1,l_2\;$ intersect:

$$(2r,2,-r)=(-1+t,2,2+2t)\iff t=-\frac35\;,\;4=-\frac45$$

so the intersection point is $\;\left(-\frac85\,,\,2\,,\,\frac45\right)\;$

and the distance of this point from the origin is

$$\sqrt{\frac{64}{25}+4+\frac{16}{25}}=\sqrt\frac{180}{25}=\sqrt\frac{36}5=\frac6{\sqrt5}$$

Comment: Nice work, @Don'A. How'd it go this long without an upvote! (+1)